# Power BI - Evaluate the logic and Highlight the subtotals (Conditional Formatting)

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to highlight the **subtotals** of a matrix based on conditions (Dynamic Measure).
This Requirement is very much do-able in Excel. But, Can we do the same with Power BI.

[image: An Working Example on MS Excel]

The Subtotal row (Total on the screenshot) has been highlighted as red if the allocation is more than the capacity and highlighted as green if the allocation is lesser than the capacity and when it is equal it is highlighted in Yellow.

Adding the thread postponed on the Power BI Community here :- https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/17401381-conditional-formatting-for-total-and-subtotals-in

Kindly let me know, if this is do-able now by making changes in the Model and provide a small working example.

Comment: I don't think this is possible yet.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I think the same as well. Should I close this thread then ? or leave it out to let the other users know that it is not possible.

Comment: Please leave it. The question and the link to the ideas forum are valuable even if there is no good answer yet. Hopefully, Microsoft will enable this in the future and someone can post an update.